# Taylor Expansion with Remainder and Norm

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, taylor-expansion, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

In Freund's Nonlinear Programming lecture [notes](http://s3.amazonaws.com/mitsloan-php/wp-faculty/sites/30/2016/12/15025626/Introduction-to-Nonlinear-Optimization-and-Optimality-Conditions-fo.pdf) (pg 26), there is an expression for directional derivatives in the form of

$$
f(\bar{x}+\lambda d) = 
f(\bar{x}) + 
\lambda \nabla f(\bar{x})^T d + 
\lambda ||d|| \alpha(\bar{x},\lambda d)
$$

where $\alpha(\bar{x},\lambda d) \to 0$ as $\lambda \to 0$. This is from the definition for $f(\cdot)$ at $\bar{x}$ being differentiable if there exists a vector $\nabla f(\bar{x})$ such that the above holds.

Another definition using the Hessian $H$,

$$
f(\bar{x}+\lambda d) = 
f(\bar{x}) + 
\lambda \nabla f(\bar{x})^T d + 
\frac{1}{2} \lambda^2 d^T H(\bar{x}) d +
\lambda^2 ||d||^2 \alpha(\bar{x},\lambda d)
$$

where, again, $\alpha(\bar{x},\lambda d) \to 0$ as $\lambda \to 0$.

I understand these are merely Taylor expansions utilizing first and the other using second order terms. But the remainder terms looks odd, I've never seen usage like this. Why the norm for $d$? Where does $\alpha$ come from? How can one derive these expressions?

Thanks,

Comment: What looks odd? Maybe try using the 1D Taylor theorem on the 1D function $F(\lambda) = f(x+\lambda d)$. That whole expression with $\alpha$ and norm of $d$ looks like it just comes out directly from the Lagrange form of the remainder

Comment: For Taylor expansion with the Hessian I see statements like $.. + O(||h||^3)$ but nothing with a square norm. I looked for Lagrange form of the remainder, didn't look like norm was used? Do you have any refs for multidimensional expansion and norm usage?

Comment: +O(\|h\|^3) is not what I said, lagrange form of remainder has $F^{(3)}(\xi)$ at some point, and the norms of $d$ pop out when you try to use the above definition of $F$. For instance note that $F' = \nabla f \cdot d$ so for the 1st order Taylor (i.e. MVT) you have for some $\tilde\lambda \in (0,\lambda)$
$$ f(x+\lambda d) = f(x) + \lambda \nabla f(x+\tilde \lambda d) \cdot d $$
and by Cauchy-Schwarz $|\nabla f(x+\tilde \lambda d) \cdot d| \le \|d\| \|\nabla f(x+\tilde \lambda d)\|$
which is of the required error form. In short you should just do the computation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Calvin, the $|d|$ comes from the fact that the directional derivative is in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let me say some words here.

If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ has all its $n$ partial derivatives over $U$, we say $f$ is of class $C^{1}$. Now, let's assume $f$ is $C^{1}$ and take $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ for simplicity. Fix $\bar{x} = (\bar{x_{1}},\bar{x_{2}}) \in U$ and take $v = (h,k)$ such that $\bar{x}+v \in B \subset U$, where $B$ is an open ball with center $\bar{x}$. Define $r(v) = r(h,k)$ by $$r(v) = f(\bar{x_{1}}+h,\bar{x_{2}}+k)-f(\bar{x_{1}},\bar{x_{2}})-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}h-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}k.$$
Now, we can write $$ r(v) = f(\bar{x_{1}}+h,\bar{x_{2}}+k)-f(\bar{x_{1}},\bar{x_{2}}+k)+f(\bar{x_{1}},\bar{x_{2}}+k)-f(\bar{x_{1}},\bar{x_{2}}) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}h - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}k $$
Now, we can use the Mean Value Theorem for real functions to find $\theta_{1},\theta_{2} \in (0,1)$ such that
$$r(v) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\bar{x_{1}}+\theta_{1}h,\bar{x_{2}}+k)h +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\bar{x_{1}},\bar{x_{2}}+\theta_{2}k)k -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}h - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}k $$
Thus $$ \frac{r(v)}{|v|} = \bigg{[} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\bar{x_{1}}+\theta_{1}h,\bar{x_{2}}+k)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\bar{x_{1}},\bar{x_{2}})\bigg{]}\frac{h}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}} + \bigg{[}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\bar{x_{1}},\bar{x_{2}}+\theta_{2}k)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\bar{x_{1}},\bar{x_{2}})\bigg{]}\frac{k}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}}.$$
If we take $v \to 0$, the continuity of the derivatives implies that the terms inside both $[\cdots]$ go to zero and because $h/\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}} \le 1$ and, $k/\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}} \le 1$, we readily see that $r(v)/|v| \to 0$.